# How to globaly initialize variable in c and what is the difference between static and extern?

Tags: c, variables, scope, global-variables, local-variables

please explain me about how a variable scope can be globally initialized in C and what is the difference between static and extern

Comment: At the file level, `static` means the variable is local to the file, and not visible to other files (compilation units).  `extern` means it's global and visible to other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of variable means: Where can it be seen (aka where does it exist) and thereby be accessed.

The scope of a variable depends on where in the code it is defined.

A variable gets global scope when it is defined **outside** a function. The keyword `static` can limit the scope of a global variable so that it can only be seen in that particular c-file (aka compilation unit). So:

**file1.c**

```
int gInt1;         // Global variable that can be seen by all c-files

static int gInt2;  // Global variable that can be seen only by this c-file

void foo(void)
{
    int lInt;  // Local variable 

    ...
}
```

In order to use a global variable from another c-file, you tell the compiler that it exists in some other file. For this you use the `extern` keyword.

**file2.c**

```
extern int gInt1;  // Now gInt1 can be used in this file

void bar(void)
{
    int n = gInt1 * (gInt1 + 1);

    ...
}
```

You often put the `extern` declaration into a header file. Like:

**file1.h**

```
extern int gInt1;  // Any c-file that includes file1.h can use gInt1
```

**file2.c**

```
#include "file1.h" // Now gInt1 can be used in this file

void bar(void)
{
    int n = gInt1 * (gInt1 + 1);

    ...
}
```

**Regarding initialization**

Initializing a global variable is no different from initializing a local variable.

The only difference between global and local variables is when you do **not** have an initializer. In such cases a local variable will be left **uninitialized** while global variables will be **default initialized** (which typically means initialized to zero).

**file1.c**

```
int gInt1 = 42;         // Global variable explicit initialized to 42

int gInt2;              // Global variable default initialized to 0

void foo(void)
{
    int lInt1 = 42;     // Local variable explicit initialized to 42

    int lInt2;          // Local variable uninitialized. Value is ??
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Declare a variable of global scope ,just declare it outside all functions.

Intial value -0.

Scope of Global variable: It can be used in all functions and files.

Life- Till Program execution.

Use of `extern keyword`:

If you declared a global variable in a file and want to use it in another file then `extern`  keyword is used.

```
int x=5;        //source file

extrern int x=10;   //any other file
```

Another use of `extern`  keyword is if the golbal variable is used before declaration in program.
example:

```
void main()
{
 int x
 extern int y;
 x=y;
} 
int y=5;
```

Static varialbe:

intial value-0

scope- Till control remain in block,function or file.

Life -Till Program execution.

```
void main()
{
fun();
fun();
fun();
}
void fun()
{
int x=0;
x++;
}
```

After Program ends x=3.

Static Variable can also be used as global variable and declared outside all functions
but the scope remain in the file in which it is defined.
example:

```
static int x=2;
int main()
{
 x=5;
}
```

That's all!